# Nextcloud, Windows Domain, Mail all the same Accounts. But how?

Tags: email, active-directory, ldap, samba, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud Server and i want to add an Windows Domain Server (like Samba4) and an Mail Server like Postfix or something. But how can i connect them all together? So that i make an account and automatically an emailadress will be created plus an nextcloud account when the user is in the VPN group. I have no idea what to use to connect these things together.

Comment: Try asking in Serverfault.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Wrong place, try on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   As you said, you are using Nextcloud server, that means it is installed on a Linux VM or system as an enterprise edition of Nextcloud Server. It can be integrated with Active Directory and the user objects created in Active Directory will be used to login to Nextcloud as well as set permissions for the files and other tasks supported. After the basic installation, the administrator setting up Nextcloud must go to the user management settings and connect to the Active Directory services to be able to manage users in one place, on the Windows Server. Once, that has been done, following support for tasks is enabled through LDAP connectivity: -

1. LDAP group support
2. File sharing with Nextcloud users and groups
3. Access via WebDAV and Nextcloud Desktop Client
4. Versioning, external Storage and all other Nextcloud features
5. Seamless connectivity to Active Directory, with no extra configuration required
6. Support for primary groups in Active Directory
7. Auto-detection of LDAP attributes such as base DN, email, and the LDAP server port number
8. Only read access to your LDAP (edit or delete of users on your LDAP is not supported)
9. Optional: Allow users to change their LDAP password from Nextcloud

For more information on configuring this, please refer the Nextcloud documentation below: -

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_auth_ldap.html

Also, if you have some issues while configuring Nextcloud directly with Active Directory, you can use a third party platform named UCS(Univention Corporate Server) with Nextcloud image to connect with Active Directory domain and facilitate the synchronization quite easier than the above. Please refer the below link for more details: -

https://nextcloud.com/blog/integrating-nextcloud-in-your-active-directory-domain-with-ucs/

•   While for postfix mail server configuration with Active Directory, you will have to configure the postfix mail server utility on a Linux system and then enable the server lookups, DN configuration and other mail related protocol which will enable Postfix to look up email addresses in Active Directory. Please refer the below links for detailed configuration information: -

https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix-dovecot-authentication-against-active-directory-on-centos-5.x

In this way, you will be able to use the Nextcloud and postfix mail server with Active Directory identities that can access the these services directly with preferred AD attributes.